# Executing a Couchbase query in Scala?

Tags: scala, akka, couchbase, akka-stream, akka-http

I have a Scala project that uses a Couchbase database and connects through ReactiveCouchbase. I have written the below query:

```
def findAll(): Any = {
  plannerBucket
    .search(N1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM planner WHERE area='area'"))
    .asSource.map(area => (area \ "message").as[String].toUpperCase)
    .runWith(Sink.seq[String])
}
```

I am invoking the function like so in an Akka HTTP route:

```
path("all-activities") {
  get {
    complete {
      HttpResponse(200, entity = CouchDriver.findAll())
    }
  }
}
```

However, I can't run it as I get the response:

```
Type mismatch,expected:ResponseEntity
Actual: Any
```

Not sure how to resolve this!

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to adjust the return type of the `findAll` method to reflect the materialized value of the stream, which is a `Future[Seq[String]]`:

```
def findAll(): Future[Seq[String]] = {
  plannerBucket
    .search(N1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM planner WHERE area='area'"))
    .asSource
    .map(area => (area \ "message").as[String].toUpperCase)
    .runWith(Sink.seq[String])
}
```

The `complete` directive can take a `Future`:

```
path("all-activities") {
  get {
    complete(CouchDriver.findAll)
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you could pass a `Source` to the `complete` directive:

```
def findAll(): Source[String, _] = {
  plannerBucket
    .search(N1qlQuery("SELECT * FROM planner WHERE area='area'"))
    .asSource
    .map(area => (area \ "message").as[String].toUpperCase)
}
```